# Different behaviour between same implementations of TensorFlow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have TensorFlow 1.9 and Keras 2.0.8 on my machine. When training a neural network with some toy data, the resulting training curves are very different between TensorFlow and Keras, and I do not understand why.

For the Keras implementation, the network learns well and the loss continues to decrease, whereas for the TensorFlow implementation, the network does not learn anything and the loss does not decrease. I have tried to ensure that both implementations use the same hyperparameters. **Why is the behaviour so different?**

The network itself has two inputs: and image, and a vector. These are then passed through their own layers, before being concatenated.

Here are my implementations.

Tensorflow:

```
# Create the placeholders
input1 = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 64, 64, 3])
input2 = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 4])
label = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 4])

# Build the TensorFlow network
# Input 1
x1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input1, filters=30, kernel_size=[5, 5], strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', activation=tf.nn.relu)
x1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=x1, filters=30, kernel_size=[5, 5], strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', activation=tf.nn.relu)
x1 = tf.layers.flatten(x1)
x1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x1, units=30)
# Input 2
x2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input2, units=30, activation=tf.nn.relu)
# Output
x3 = tf.concat(values=[x1, x2], axis=1)
x3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x3, units=30)
prediction = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x3, units=4)

# Define the optimisation
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(label - prediction))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

# Train the model
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
training_feed = {input1: training_input1_data, input2: training_input2_data, label: training_label_data}
validation_feed = {input1: validation_input1_data, input2: validation_input2_data, label: validation_label_data}
for epoch_num in range(30):
    train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, train_op], feed_dict=training_feed)
    val_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=validation_feed)
```

Keras:

```
# Build the keras network
# Input 1
input1 = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3), name='input1')
x1 = Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=5, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', activation='relu')(input1)
x1 = Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=5, strides=(2, 2), padding='valid', activation='relu')(x1)
x1 = Flatten()(x1)
x1 = Dense(units=30, activation='relu')(x1)
# Input 2
input2 = Input(shape=(4,), name='input2')
x2 = Dense(units=30, activation='relu')(input2)
# Output
x3 = keras.layers.concatenate([x1, x2])
x3 = Dense(units=30, activation='relu')(x3)
prediction = Dense(units=4, activation='linear', name='output')(x3)

# Define the optimisation
model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=[prediction])
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='mse')

# Train the model
training_inputs = {'input1': training_input1_data, 'input2': training_input2_data}
training_labels = {'output': training_label_data}
validation_inputs = {'input1': validation_images, 'input2': validation_state_diffs}
validation_labels = {'output': validation_label_data}
callback = PlotCallback()
model.fit(x=training_inputs, y=training_labels, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_labels), batch_size=len(training_label_data[0]), epochs=30)
```

And here are the training curves (two runs for each implementation).

Tensorflow:

[image]
[image]

Keras:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the batch size is the same?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. For TensorFlow, the entire "training_label_data" is fed in using the feed. For Keras, the argument is set "batch_size=len(training_label_data[0])". So both implementations use the entire training set.

Comment: Well, from your TF implementation I am guessing that `len(training_label_data[0])=4`.

Comment: I’m not sure why you think my TF code should imply this... The number of training examples is actually 100, but this isn’t specified in either implementation — it is inferred from the data variables themselves.

Comment: The number of training examples is `len(training_label_data)` instead of `len(training_label_data[0])`, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, sorry. The batch size should be `len(training_label_data)`. As it happens, it doesn't make a difference, because `len(training_label_data[0])` is actually larger than `len(training_label_data)`, and if the specified batch size is too big then I believe it reduces the batch size to fit the data.

Comment: Could you please: 1. Print these values. 2. Try what happens when you change the batch size of TF to `len(training_label_data[0])`

Comment: Ok, interesting development. I was wrong again: `len(training_label_data[0]` is only 4, and so smaller than `len(training_label_data)`. Therefore, the batch size is different in the two implementations; it is much smaller with the Keras implementation. When I changed the TensorFlow implementation to have a batch size of 4, the training curve was more similar to that of the Keras implementation, and it was actually able to reduce the loss. So it seems that a smaller batch size here allows the optimisation to avoid a local minimum, perhaps because the gradients are more stochastic....?

Comment: Yes, that is what I presumed from the beginning. Let me write an answer explaining why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After carefully examining your implementations, I observed that all the hyperparameters match except for the batch size. I don't agree with the answer from @Ultraviolet, because the default `kernel_initializer` of `tf.layers.conv2d` is also Xavier (see the TF implementation of [conv2d](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L323)).

The learning curves don't match for the following two reasons:

1. The parameters from the Keras implementation (version 2) are receiving many more updates than those of the TF implementation (version 1). In version 1, you're feeding the full dataset simultaneously into the network at each epoch. This results in only 30 adam updates. In contrast, version 2 is performing `30 * ceil(len(training_label_data)/batch_size)` adam updates, with `batch_size=4`.
2. The updates of version 2 are noisier than those of version 1, because the gradients are averaged over less samples.

Comment: +1 for discovering the batch size issue. However, I am still not sure that why are saying the  None in keras and sets the initialization to xavier?

Comment: Looking into this I didn't notice anywhere saying `None` is `glorot_uniform` which is default in keras. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f202958ee2d5177a474e3d107fdbf0c83174d099/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py

Comment: Thanks @rvinas. Do you think that if the optimiser was vanilla gradient descent, rather than Adam, then the batch size would still have an effect? What I mean is: does the smaller batch size help the optimisation because (i) Adam has its own internal parameters which are updated on each batch, and so a smaller batch size means more updates to these internal parameters, or is it because (ii) A smaller batch size means that the gradients are more stochastic, and therefore it is easier for the optimisation to find paths out of a local minimum? Or is it due to both?

Comment: @Ultraviolet Note that `tf.layers.conv2d` instantiates the class defined in [L227](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L227), which inherits from `keras.layers.Conv2D` (and the Keras `kernel_initializer` argument is set to the TF `kernel_initializer`: [L311](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L311)).

Comment: yes but we did set it to None here and the none is set as the initializer https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25c197e02393bd44f50079945409009dd4d434f8/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L332

Comment: @Karnivaurus Yes, the batch size would still have a similar effect. (i) I didn't mean the Adam parameters in particular, I meant all the model's parameters. (ii) Yes, smaller batch sizes are more noisy, and they might occasionally help escape a local minima.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice any difference between the two implementations of yours. Assuming there is none, I think,

- First thing is that they started at different **initial losses**.
  That suggests that the initializations of the graphs are different.
  As you didn't mention any initializer. Looking into the documentation
  ([tensorflow Conv2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d), [Keras Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)) I have found that the
  default initializers are different.

  `tensorflow` uses **no initializer** on the other hand `Keras` uses
  **Xavier initializer**.
- Second thing is that (this is my assumption) `tensorflow` loss is very sharply decreased initially but later didin't decrease much compared to the `Keras` one. As the designed network is not very robust and not very deep, because of the bad initialization `tensorflow` suffered by falling into local minima.
- Thirdly, there may be some little differences between the two as the
  default parameter may vary. Generally, the wrapper frameworks try to
  handle some default parameters so that we need fewer tweaks to get to
  the optimal weights.
  I have used **FastAI** framework based on
  `pytorch` and **Keras** framework for a certain classification
  problem using same VGG network. I have got a significant improvement in **FastAI**. Because
  it's default parameters are recently tweaked with the latest best
  practices.

### Edit:

I failed to notice that the batch size was different which is one of the most important hyperparameters here. **@rvinas** made it clear in his answer.

Comment: TensorFlow and Keras use the same initializer for conv2d: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py#L323

Comment: I don't know the internal implementation but the document says, kernel initializer is **None** for tensorflow but for Keras it's **Xavier**

Comment: I know the documentation says that `kernel_initializer` is `None` by default, but this does not mean that the variables don't have an initializer. All the variables need to be initialized in some manner, and this manner is Xavier initialization both in Keras and TensorFlow. In fact, `tf.layers.conv2d` is directly using `keras.layers.Conv2D`, so setting `kernel_initializer=None` in TF results in using the default Keras `kernel_initializer`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me to debug. I tried increasing the size of the network (as suggested in your second point), and this then enabled the TensorFlow implementation to learn, so it was stuck in a local minimum before. There is still a significant difference between the two implementations, perhaps due to initialisation, but at least now my TensorFlow implementation is actually reducing the loss.

Comment: I also tried reducing the batch size in the TensorFlow implementation (in my original implementation, the batch size was actually much smaller with Keras). This also allowed the TensorFlow implementation to avoid a local minimum and hence reduce the loss.